# What is the meaning of this max function notation?

Tags: functions

I am studying about max and min function.But I am unable to figure out the meaning of this below notation.
$$
(x-100)^+
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(z)^+=\max(z,0)$$
If $f$ is a function $f^+$ is is positive part.